# Jquery addClass is not working?

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on any categories it is adding class as "active", but when I click on other, then categories it is refreshing and class is removed. how to resolve this?

Below is HTML code,

```
<div class="flDropDiv category_fl">
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Fitted bed Sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Flat bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet"> Flat bed sheet  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Full bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twin bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> Twin bed sheet  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twinxl bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twinxl-bed-sheets"> Twinxl bed sheets   </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Queen bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/queen-bed-sheet"> Queen bed sheet  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-bed-sheets"> King bed sheets  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Cal king bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/cal-king-bed-sheets"> Cal king bed sheets  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Duvet covers " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/duvet-covers"> Duvet covers  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Bed skirts " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/bed-skirts"> Bed skirts  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Standard Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/standard-pillow-cases"> Standard Pillow cases  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-pillow-cases"> King Pillow cases  </a> </div>
                            <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Pillow shells " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/pillow-shells"> Pillow shells  </a> </div>
                        </div>
```

Jquery Code,

```
    var localStorageIndex = "clickedLink";
$(function() {
  $(".category_filter").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass("active")){
    return;
    }
    var clickedLink = getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage();
    if(clickedLink !== e.target.href){
      clickedLink = e.target.href;
      $(e.target).addClass("active");
      localStorage.setItem(localStorageIndex, clickedLink);
    }
  })

  function getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem(localStorageIndex);
  }

  function initActiveLink(){
    var clickedLink = getActiveLinkFromLocalStorage();
    if(!clickedLink){
      return;
    }
      localStorage.clear();
      $("a[href='" + clickedLink + "'].category_filter").addClass("active");
  }
  initActiveLink();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
   $(".category_filter li a").each(function() {
       $(this).click(function() {
           $(".category_filter li a").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
      });
}); 
});
```

```css
.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="categories-filters">
<ul class="category_filter">
<li><a href="#">Filter 1 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Filter 2 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Filter 3 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Filter 4 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I click other links like color filter or price filter it is removing active class.

Comment: So you don't want to remove ".active" class?

Comment: No I dont want remove active when I click on other filters

Comment: No still it is removing only.

Comment: @jishnu I should store in localstorage in my case.

Comment: @Mohan Please check now.

Comment: Not category links it should not remove when we click other than category filters

Comment: Hi @Mohan, could you please provide more brief, what exactly you want to achieve?

This is what I'm assuming...

There are categories filter and all of them added ".category_filter" class. You just want to add the ".active"  class on click event?

There are 2 thing you may want to achieve .....
1. You want to add ".active" class on click event and it will remove from the previous link.

2. You want to add ".active" class on click event and it will not remove from the previous link..  Please confirm, what exactly you want to achieve, so I can help you accordingly.

Comment: Actually I want to add active class for category filter if there are other filters like price or color is there means If i click color filter means active class is removing for category filter this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: It should remove active class when I click on other filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139452/discussion-between-rahul-kumar-and-mohan).

Answer (score 0):

it's refreshing because u field href with url. if you need url link ucan use attribute for helping you know the uri on tag . this a simple example to add class hactive on class "category_filter"

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click",".category_filter", function(){
     /* to remove class, uncomment this if you want to remove class $(".category_filter").removeClass("hactive");*/

   //if you want to get the uri data u can use;
   var uriData = $(this).attr("data-uriex");
   $(this).addClass("hactive");

   //sample view the single uri when click.
   $("#justClick").html("<b>uri data click :</b> "+uriData);

   //sample for get all uri on hactive class;
   var cekData = "", i =0;
   $(".hactive").each(function(){
     cekData = cekData+"data URI Active: "+(i+1)+" "+$(this).attr("data-uriex")+"<br/>";i++;
   });
   $("#AllUri").html(cekData);
  });
 });
```

```css
 .hactive{
  color : #f00;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flDropDiv category_fl">
 <div class="flItems">
  <a class="category_filter" data-value="Fitted bed Sheet " href="#" 
   data-uriex="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet">  
   Fitted bed Sheet  
  </a> 
 </div>
 <div class="flItems">
  <a class="category_filter" data-value="Flat bed sheet " href="#" data-uriex="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet">
   Flat bed sheet  
   </a> 
 </div>
  <div class="flItems">
   <a class="category_filter" data-value="Full bed sheets"  href="#" data-uriex="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets">
     Full bed sheets   
   </a> 
  </div>
  <div class="flItems">
   <a class="category_filter" data-value="Twin bed sheet"  href="#" data-uriex="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> 
    Twin bed   sheet  
   </a> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="justClick"></div>
 <hr/>
<div id ="AllUri"></div>
```